# How to query Blazor-server API before connecting SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have Blazor-Server app and I want to call the below API  in JS  before starting Blazor SignalR conenction on the Browser

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HostInfoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return Environment.MachineName;
    }
        
}
```

Basically I would need to call this api to retrieve physical hostname that I need to initialize Blazor SignalR because, http is going through a portal, which for internal infra limitation, doesn't support well the SignalR traffic going through WebSocket, so I cannot use same base url as http.

```html
<script>
    (function start() {
        var hostname = // Call /api/hostinfo  (ex : axios.get(/api/hostinfo))

        var signalRUrl = 'ws://' + hostname + ':6400/_blazor'; 

        Blazor.start({
            configureSignalR: builder => builder.withUrl(signalRUrl)
        });
    })();
</script>
```

I guess I can do it with axios, but there is probably a builtin function in Blazor api to do so...

This is related to this question [How can I configure Blazor to use different base URLs for HTTP and WebSocket connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300405/how-can-i-configure-blazor-to-use-different-base-urls-for-http-and-websocket-con) where I needed to bypass the http portal to establish the SignalR connection

Comment: "Call ... in JS" before "starting in the Browser" makes little sense. You can call JS in OnAfterRender(true).

Comment: @HH  it does make sense, because it's requirement for me to establish SignalR connection, and without this connection there is no OnAfterRender() callback and no JS/.Net integration